# Eclipse (2018-09) CDT project with Cygwin, can't debug the binary

Tags: eclipse, gdb, cygwin

It seems that everything cygwin-related configured and works fine in my Eclipse project, for example Eclipse is able to invoke 'make' or 'gcc', and can even run the compiled binary and show the output in the Eclipse console window.

However, when I try to debug my binary within Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
```

I do able to launch gdb from my Cygwin console, so it is installed correctly (I assume). But why it fails when I try to use it from Eclipse?

Comment: `The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135)` so what are the needs of your program ?

Comment: No special needs, it runs perfectly fine when I just "Run" it in Eclipse, I get this error only when I try to use the debugger.

Comment: gdb depends on 11 dlls. It is possible that Eclipse eats some address space and it collides with loading the program or gdb. Are you using 32 or 64 bit Cygwin ?

Comment: Yes, I use 64-bit Cygwin.And this gdb - GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 8.1.1-1) 8.1.1.

Comment: Turns out that I actually forgot to add Cygwin bin folder to the PATH variable. Which is strange because 'make' and 'gcc' commands worked fine. So problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, as you say, it turns out that adding the Cygwin bin folder to the PATH variable solves this problem.

I use Eclipse 2020-06 and Cygwin 64bit on Win7 64bit. And installing Cygwin doesn't change the PATH variable currently.

But it is also confused to me that "build" and "run" work fine in Eclipse whithout the Cygwin bin in PATH.